# How would I store some encrypted strings in Mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, string, encryption

How do I store some encrypted strings (just about one to a couple of words)?

Let's suppose I encrypted this string:

```
$key='fappings'; // Encryption Key
$str='Mama Luigi'; // String that I Encrypted
$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key)));
```

Now, assuming I don't want to index that data, or perform any searches on it, just wanna ask two questions:

1. What datatype would I better use? I would guess varbinary, but I'm not sure...
2. How would I make process my query? Assuming I would use a simple mysql_query() function.

I saw some people would actually make base64 encode, and then simply insert it, just the way a normal string would go, eg:

```
mysql_query("insert into faps data='".base64_encode($encrypted)."'");
```

But something tells me it's not the way to do it. Even space-wise insufficient.

What would be a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a varbinary (as you suggest) or a blob, depending on length required. For safety, multiply the length of the string by 4.

No need to base64 encode it - that just adds yet more length. All you need are the regular escaping functions (mysql_real_escape_string at a basic level, or bind using PDO and it'll make it safe for you).

An alternative may be to use MySql's own encryption functions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html as this may save you some programming hassles? Moves the stress from PHP server to MySQL server - so consider which is less stressed, and whether travelling of the uncompressed SQL instructions over an open network matters etc.

Comment: Well I wouldn't go for custom encryption, that's funny to play with ofc, but I'm not just not in a mood for that, and I've got one that already works well. I also noted that I wouldn't consider PDO either. But As what I can understand, it is safe to use mysql_real_escape_string($encrypted) for storage? The data is binary and is not string, so I just don't know... I'm just being cautious, I would appreciate if you could answer on that.

Comment: Yes, you can store binary data with mySQL_real_escape_sting.

Comment: Thanks, that actually did the trick :) I couldn't think it was as simple as escaping it with escape string even though it was binary